# Clicking on Link returns a function, React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a Sign in and Sign up page. Both sign in and sign up will be shown on the same page, without redirecting it to another page. 
Right now, I have two functions showSignUp and showSignIn. These two returns the form. I then render them by calling {this.showSignIn()}. I have a button says "Sign In", and a Link saying "Create a new account". Clicking on the create a new account should show the "Sign up" form. I inserted my showSignIn() function below. The showSignUp function is similar to this.

But I am unsure how should I solve the clicking on a link calls another function.

{I solved the problem by creating one js file for sign in and one for sign up previously. But this cause alot of repetitive code. That is why I am trying to merging them.}

```
return (
  <form>
    <div className="login-screen">
      <div className="formField">
        <label className="formField-Label" htmlFor="name">
          E-mail
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          className="formField-Input"
          placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="formField">
        <label className="formField-Label" htmlFor="password">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          className="formField-Input"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="formField">
        <button className="form-button" onClick={this.signin}>
          Sign In
        </button>
        <Link to={this.showSignUp} className="form-link">
          Create a new account
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
);
```

Comment: You put it in a component and control stuff through props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your `Link` comes from `react-router-dom`, so it only accepts `string` or `object` as `to` prop, see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link.

You should replace it with a `<button onClick={this.showSignUp}>Create...</button>`

Note that your `showSignUp` function should trigger a state change in order to render again and change the form displayed. It would look something like :

```
state = {
  showSignUp: false,
}

renderSignUp() {
  return (
    <form>
      // ...
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showSignUp: false })} className="form-link">Create a new account</button> 
   </form>
  );
}

renderSignIn() {
  // Returns your sign in form
}

render() {
  return this.state.showSignUp ? this.renderSignUp() : this.renderSignIn();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! I knew I needed some javascript condition inside the render, but had a hard time figuring out how to write it! Thanks once again!

Comment: @NahidaIslam you're welcome ! Please mark my answer as the solution you used :)

Answer (score 0):

I second adesurirey's answer, but it doesn't have to be a button, you can attach and onClick listener to just about any html element so if you wanted it to behave more like a normal link it could even be an `<a />` tag with no new route or a `<span>` that you style to look like a `<Link>`

Comment: That would work but it would also break HTML accessibility rules. Links, buttons and spans have their own purpose :)